# NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to upgrade to Spring - 4.3.4.RELEASE,
Spring-security 4.2.3

```
Here is what I have in my pom.xml
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>    
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>          
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>           
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
```

When I start my server, I am getting an error of NoSuchMethodError,

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/NamedBeanHolder;
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:579)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:546)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:707)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:680)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)
```

which is for the Spring Beans library missing this `resolveNamedBean`method. I have found that this method was introduced since spring 4.3.3. But my dilemma is that I do not have an older version of spring-bean anywhere in my pom or in my local repository.
Where do I start looking for the older version of the bean library? Could someone please point me in the right direction as I am just stuck.

I would appreciate any suggestion.
Thanks

[screenshot of what my local repository has for spring bean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci6rT.png)

[Screenshot of what JARS in my Maven dependencies folder in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2jcz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what version of `spring-orm` you have in directory with compiled classes. Seems like your project is not fully recompiled. Try to recompile everything in order to be sure that in runtime you have appropriate version of `spring-beans`. Now it looks like new up-to-date version of `spring-orm` tries to utilize old version of `spring-beans`.

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you!....Yes when I looked at my Tomcat app directory it still had old jars. I removed the project and re-publised. It is good now. Thanks again Andrei.